# Get Bitmap image from Url

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap

I want to get `Bitmap` image from `Url`:

```
Bitmap mage = getBitmapFromUrl(urlPhotoInFrameFirst);

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl (String uri){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        return image;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But app stop in this line:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
>               at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
>               at com.example.sivolotskiy.multiexpro.util.BitmapLoader.getBitmapFromUrl(BitmapLoader.java:33)
>               at com.example.sivolotskiy.multiexpro.ui.EditFragment.setImageInFrames(EditFragment.java:161)
>               at com.example.sivolotskiy.multiexpro.ui.EditFragment.startAfterView(EditFragment.java:119)
>               at com.example.sivolotskiy.multiexpro.ui.EditFragment_.onViewChanged(EditFragment_.java:202)
>               at org.androidannotations.api.view.OnViewChangedNotifier.notifyViewChanged(OnViewChangedNotifier.java:41)
>               at com.example.sivolotskiy.multiexpro.ui.EditFragment_.onViewCreated(EditFragment_.java:71)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:843)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: obviously `url.openConnection()` returns `null`. Can you dig into that a bit and update your question? The Full Stack Trace would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As exception says you can't make network calls in the Main(UI) thread. So you need to wrap your code into runnable/thread and call it. Could look like this:

```
public static class GetBitmapTask implements Runnable {

    private final String uri;
    private final Callback callback;

    public GetBitmapTask(String uri, Callback callback) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            callback.onFinish(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callback.onError(e);
        }
    }

    public interface Callback{
        void onFinish(Bitmap bitmap);
        void onError(Throwable t);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new Thread(new GetBitmapTask("", new GetBitmapTask.Callback() {
    @Override public void onFinish(Bitmap bitmap) {
        //here is your bitmap
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
        //here you have to handle error
    }
})).start();
```

**Or even better method**: [use a library for loading images](https://github.com/square/picasso).